# Implementation of a recursive binary search

Tags: java, search, binary

I am writing a program that stores appointments in an ArrayList. The user is asked to type in a date, a start time, and an end time for an appointment. The program needs to check if there is already an appointment at the time the user wants to submit a new appointment. This is the recursive binary search part. Here is what I have implemented so far.

Method:

```
public boolean overlap(ArrayList<Appointment> list, int start, int end, 
                       Calendar startCal, Calendar endCal)
{
    int middle = (start + end)/2;
    System.out.println("Start: " + start + " End: " + end + " Middle: " + middle);

    Appointment appt = list.get(middle);
    if(start == end){
        return((startCal.compareTo(appt.getStart()) >= 0 && startCal.compareTo(appt.getEnd()) <= 0 ) ||
                endCal.compareTo(appt.getEnd()) <= 0 && endCal.compareTo(appt.getStart()) >= 0 );
    }
    else if(startCal.compareTo(appt.getStart()) <= 0 && endCal.compareTo(appt.getStart()) <= 0){
        return overlap(list, start, middle - 1, startCal, endCal);
    }
    else{
        return overlap(list, middle, end, startCal, endCal); 
    }  
}
```

How I am calling it:

```
case 1 : //Enter a new appointment
                setCal();
                startDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute);
                endDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, endHour, endMinute);

                appt = new Appointment(description, startDate, endDate);

                if(apptList.isEmpty()){
                    apptList.add(appt);
                }
                else{
                    boolean isOverlap = overlap(apptList, 0, apptList.size() - 1, 
                                        appt.getStart(), appt.getEnd());

                    if(isOverlap){
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("ERROR: There is already an appointment at that time");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    else{
                        int indexToBeAdded = indexFinder(apptList, 0, apptList.size() -1, 
                                                       appt.getStart(), appt.getEnd());
                        Appointment tmp = apptList.get(indexToBeAdded);

                        if(tmp.start.compareTo(appt.start) < 0){
                            apptList.add(indexToBeAdded + 1, appt);   
                        }
                        else{
                            apptList.add(indexToBeAdded , appt);
                        }
                    }
                }
                choice = 0;
                break;
```

setCal() simply prompts the user for all the calendar parameters and sets them based on what they type in. Also indexFinder is another recursive binary search method that finds the index that the appointment should be added so that the appointment gets added in the correct order.

As of now upon the third appointment I try to add I get a stack overflow exception.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) What is your question?

Comment: My specific problem is that I cannot figure out why I am getting a stack overflow error once I get to the third appointment I am trying to add

Comment: I would imagine `middle -> start = 0`, `end != 0`. Of course the output *which is not included* should say exactly what recurses incorrectly. (This is why I gave a -1: we can't read your console.)

Comment: When asking a question about an error, post the error; the question should be "why do I get this error in this code", with full stacktrace, the input you supplied, and the output that came out. And even then, you have to make it interesting; people do not want to debug for you. Why are you sure that your code is correct? How did you try to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return overlap(list, start, middle - 1, startCal, endCal);`

If you call overlap with start = 0 and end = 1, middle = 0+1/2 = 0, then you call overlap with start = 0 and end = -1.. which means that they'll fly further and further apart and you skipped reach the stopping condition of `start == end`.

Try turning `start == end` into `start > end`.

EDIT: Problem two is this call

`return overlap(list, middle, end, startCal, endCal);`

If you call overlap with start = 0 and end = 1, middle = 0+1/2 = 0, so you call overlap with start = 0 and end = 1... infinite recursion loop! Stack overflow! It never ends.

To solve this, turn `middle` into `middle + 1`.

Comment: I thought this too, and I did try turning start > end, the stack overflow is still thrown upon the third entry. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @justin henricks Please see my edit

Comment: This is working seemingly, much simpler fix than I was assuming. Great to have a second set of eyes, thanks a ton man!

Comment: False alarm, still getting a stack overflow error, my method is not implemented quite right yet. I'm not sure exactly when the stack overflow is being thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: @justin henricks Nope, use a debugger ;)

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you!!